# List as JSON string in R

Tags: r, json

**Problem:** I want to convert a list object into a JSON string. In Python I can easily do this with `json.dumps()` with dictionary object.

How can I do this in R?

```
library(jsonlite)

a <- list(y = list(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(3, 4, 5)))
toJSON(a)

## Expected Outcome
"[{\"y\":{\"x\":[1,2,3],\"y\":[3,4,5]}}]"
```

Comment: Isn't `jsonlite::toJSON(a)` returning your expected output?

Comment: It returns {"y":{"x":[1,2,3],"y":[3,4,5]}} but not json string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned object from `toJSON` is of class "json", and it has its own print method so you can see the json string without distracting escape characters (similar to base R's `cat` function). To make it a standard character vector you just do:

```
as.character(toJSON(a))
#> [1] "{\"y\":{\"x\":[1,2,3],\"y\":[3,4,5]}}"
```